# UITableView doesn't scroll slowly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom cells. It scrolls every time if I swipe fast, but when I swipe more slowly, sometimes it won't scroll.

**Setup**:
UITableview controller with a standard table view. I load some images in the cells asynchronously. The cells subclassed, but the only methods I override are `awakeFromNib` and `layoutSubviews`. 
I'm setting these methods:

```
  self.scrollView.delaysContentTouches = true
    self.scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = true
```

**Symptoms**
It's almost as if the cell doesn't return the touch event to the scrollView. For example, in the Mail app, you can hold down on a cell, but if you keep scrolling, it will break the touch and allow you to scroll.

I'm being as specific as I can without dumping a bunch of code, let me know if there's any other relevant info I should add.

Comment: Why are you setting those scroll view properties?

Comment: I set those to try to fix it. With or without those properties, the problem is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to try:

- Do you have any other gesture recognizers in the view?
- If it's not necessary to have user interaction with the cells, you can disable selection in the UITableView
- Is this issue only present on hardware or also in the simulator? Depending on your hardware (i.e. older iPod Touches) some ios mobile devices have less responsive displays
- Depending on the content of your cells, you may be scrolling inside a textView or something similar. Maybe try disabling scrolling inside those controls?

Comment: I have a Pan Gesture Recognizer. It looks like this could be disrupting the scroll.